# Fastest way to make a UI for a flutter dev?

Tags: flutter, mocking, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

We’ve got a project to convert our existing browser extension into a flutter app, however I’d like to do the UI design component of this myself so that I can provide our freelancer with something to work with, I know exactly how it should look in my head already.

I was looking at Adobe XD, I know it’s got a flutter extension. Is this my best bet or is there something better? I basically want to build the entire UI of our app, and give it to our freelancer for wiring up and programming. Ideally it’d be fast to work in, as we’re trying to offload this piece of programming to a third party so we can focus on the extension programming. Or are none of these tools any good for this sort of a task?

Comment: Using the XD plugin that generates flutter widgets, is bad and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

The best workflow I had up to now, was:

1. UI/UX Designer makes the app ui in Adobe XD.
2. They upload to Zeplin via Adobe XD
3. I get all assets etc from there and use this to make the UI on my own with Material Components.

Using the XD plugin that generates flutter widgets, is bad and should be avoided.

Comment: So are you suggesting against using the XD Flutter plugin at all? In which case do I need to do anything special to make my layout compatible with Flutter? Thanks for your response!

Comment: When I tried it, a while ago, it produced too many widgets that made no sense. This is because of the specific way it treats components in XD. For me this was too much "noise" and would made the project too complicated. Thus I prefer to get the dev sheet and ui from my designer and replicate it on my own. Flutter is really easy to work with when it comes to UI, so the result is much cleaner.